# Having more than 32 bytevalues

Tags: javascript, typescript, byte, bitwise-operators

I am tasked with making a permission system using bitwise operators, and someone asked me, what if we need more than 32 permissions, 
Currently we have this:

```
enum permissions {
    none = 0,
    Founder = 1 << 0,
    SeeAdmins = 1 << 1,
    EditAdmins = 1 << 2,
    SeeText = 1 << 3,
    EditText = 1 << 4,
    PublishWork = 1 << 5
}
```

Which is managable, but it's not unthinkable that we will be adding more than 32, a quick test gave me these results:

```
1 << 30 = 1073741824
1 << 31 = -2147483648
1 << 32 = 1
```

Is it even possible to have more than 32 byte values like this?

Comment: It might be a fun thought experiment but you shouldn't really code for it unless you think it's a very real possibility you'd need more than 32 permissions. Personally, I'd just have multiple enums each of them able to have 32 permissions (contextually linked) and a user would have a permission property of each enum type. This means you can keep your current design and extend it when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of permissions in this case can be virtually infinite. But it doesn't involve a *binary mask*, you'll need to think about how you structure your permissions in your database.

1. If the permissions (permission group to be precise) are just a number then the *binary mask* is the way to go. Since it can fit in one number
2. If you want more flexibillity, just assign random IDs to permissions. Then create *permission groups* which have their own IDs. This way you have virtually an infinite number of permissions and controls

You can for example just continue adding items to your `Permission` *enum* without even giving it a number.
[Typescript will convert that to auto-incrementing numbers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). Like this

```
enum Permissions {
    none,
    Founder,
    SeeAdmins,
    EditAdmins,
    SeeText,
    EditText,
    PublishWork
}
```

In the front-end layer your *"permissions group"* may be a simple array of *permissions*

```
const accountantPermissionGroup = [
    Permissions.SeeTransactions,
    Permissions.WriteSomeReport,
    Permissions.MoveFunds
];
```

Answer (score 1):

BingInt

```
1n << 64n
18446744073709551616n
```

> BigInts support the most common operators. Binary +, -, *, and ** all
>   work as expected. / and % work, and round towards zero as needed.
>   Bitwise operations |, &, <<, >>, and ^ perform bitwise arithmetic
>   assuming a two’s complement representation for negative values, just
>   like they do for Numbers.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint